# Which version of einstein bots support rich text content?

Tags: einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

This article https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bots_service_enhanced.htm&type=5 suggest that Enhanced bots support rich text content

> Rich Content  Not supported    Supports inbound files, outbound files
>
> Supports the following messaging components:
>
> Enhanced link Time selector Question with dynamic options*
> *The plain text Static and Dynamic Question dialog steps are supported for standard and enhanced bots.
>
> The Einstein Bots API doesn’t support messaging components.

while in fact we struggle to make it work while for Standard bots we actually redefine Chat Message with a custom LWC component to display the rich context.

Is this documentation accurate or in fact, it is the Standard Chat Bot support rich text context through Chat Message customization in embedded service deployment customization but not the Enhanced bot?